# Excel - Keeping info linked after being sorted.

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to create a link that updates the formula when sorted. Here is what I have; a very large sheet that is being used as a tracker. What I would like is to be able to view specific columns in a second sheet as a summary that will maintain the information on sheet 1 after it has been sorted.

Example; on sheet 1 in column A is a list of projects, results are in column D, column G and column R. In between is more information. What I would like on the sheet 2 is to link cell A1 with cell A1 on the sheet 1. Link cell B1 on the sheet 2 to cell D1 on the sheet 1. Link cell C1 on the sheet 2 to cell G1 on the sheet 1. Then repeat down the rows.

Now here is my problem; how do i maintain the link between information as the information changes cell position if column A on sheet 1 is sorted differently?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do it with directly referenced cells. Here's a good (and simple workaround) using INDEX/MATCH:

1) Add a helper column (e.g., left of Column A) to Sheet 1 that just has the values 1...n for the n projects. For example, A1 = 1, A2 = 2, all the way down.

2) Add a similar helper column to Sheet 2. Now, instead of linking A1 on Sheet 2 to A1 on Sheet 1, use an INDEX/MATCH formula that looks up the value in Column A on Sheet 2, finds the row with corresponding value in Sheet 2, and return the appropriate value on that row (based on whatever column you want). For example

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$K$11,MATCH($A$1,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$11,0),10)
```

Where your data (including new helper column in A) now goes from A2:K11 on Sheet 1, and you want whatever value is in column #10.